# Read a UTF-8 text file with BOM

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, byte-order-mark

I have a text file with Byte order mark (U+FEFF) at the beginning. I am trying to read the file in R. Is it possible to avoid the Byte order mark?

The function `fread` (from the `data.table` package) reads the file, but adds `ļ»æ` at the beginning of the first variable name:

```
> names(frame_pers)[1]
[1] "ļ»æreg_date"
```

The same is with `read.csv` function.

Currently I have made a function which removes the BOM from the first column name, but I believe there should be a way how to automatically strip the BOM.

```
remove.BOM <- function(x) setnames(x, 1, substring(names(x)[1], 4))

> names(frame_pers)[1]
[1] "ļ»æreg_date"
> remove.BOM(frame_pers)
> names(frame_pers)[1]
[1] "reg_date"
```

I am using the native encoding for the R session:

```
> options("encoding" = "")
> options("encoding")
$encoding
[1] ""
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have you tried `read.csv(..., fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")`?. `?file` says:

> As from R 3.0.0 the encoding ‘"UTF-8-BOM"’ is accepted and will remove
>   a Byte Order Mark if present (which it often is for files and webpages
>   generated by Microsoft applications).

Comment: Also not working for me.  My raw data looks like "31.1" when copy-paste from notepad++ but in R with fread it splits into 2 columns, and with read.csv I get the following as prefix "ï»¿" (using as.is = TRUE).  I used autohotkey and convert2txt to get ocr from a gui display, and I wrote it to file.  This gives me the problem that "31.2" becomes " ï»¿.331"

Answer (score 7):

This was handled between versions 1.9.6 and 1.9.8 with [this commit](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/9fa61a9d7af633816de6efa86faeefa5392d8593); update your `data.table` installation to fix this.

Once done, you can just use `fread`:

```
fread("file_name.csv")
```

Comment: I'm using 1.10.4.  I ended up using "read_csv" and setting "col_types = "c" ", then trimming the first character before converting to numeric.  It was a kludge.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been 8 years but I just had this problem and came across this so it might help. An important detail (mentioned by hadley above) is that it needs to be fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM" not just encoding="UTF-8-BOM". "encoding" works for a few options but not UTF-8-BOM. Go figure. Found this out here: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2019/09/07/excel-r-bom/