# R is adding strange symbols when reading a csv file (Unicode)

Tags: r, unicode

When I read a CSV file R adds strange symbols at the very beginning, like this:

п.їCategory

But in the original file it's just

"Category"

Because of that problem I cannot refer to this variable.

I already checked the coding of the file, it's UTF-8. It contains some unusual symbols later (German umlauts), but not as varible names, so I don't understand why this problem appears here. Are there any ideas?..

```
data_id = read.table("subject-3.csv", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T, fill = T, sep="\t", na.strings=c("","NA"))
```

Comment: try with encoding = "UTF-8"

Comment: How did you check the encoding? Does this just affect the first column name? Is there a byte-order-marker (BOM) in the file? (possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624796/read-a-utf-8-text-file-with-bom)

Comment: @MrFlick thank you! I found out indeed that the encoding was wrong (because the file was created by using Mac, which I didn't know). I never had this problem before, because all other files were created on Windows. After using R on Mac to read the table, I got rid of this problem. I also tried your suggested method with BOM, but it didn't work (all data are read just as a single string, when there should be a table).

Comment: @PawelStradowski I found out indeed that the encoding was wrong (because the file was created by using Mac, which I didn't know). I never had this problem before, because all other files were created on Windows. After using R on Mac to read the table, I got rid of this problem.

Comment: @MrFlick I used PSPad to convert the file into UTF-8, but as I understand now it didn't work properly.