# Unrecognizable symbol in first column of R

Tags: r, read.csv

Whenever I am 'reading' in any data into R, and I proceed to 'view' this, 
The first column header contains a symbol which is preventing me from further analysis. My first column title should say: ID

Can anyone identify what this is?

```
test20<-read.csv("test20.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

When I View, this is the output:

(please see image included)

[image]

Here is a snippet of my .csv file

[image]

Comment: You can use `read.csv("test20.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", check.names = FALSE)`. If there are any non-standard names in the column names the `check.names` which is `TRUE` by default will do a check and convert the spaces etc to `.`

Comment: Thank you, I am still getting a symbol. I will further research this.

Comment: Can you. check the output in console instead of `View`

Comment: yes, it shows the same symbol.

Comment: If looks like you have a UTF-8 CSV file with a BOM (byte order marker). Use the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624796/read-a-utf-8-text-file-with-bom

Comment: yes this worked!     read.csv(" " ,fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")  thank you!