# Why does the column name change after open the dataset in R?

Tags: r, import

I imported an excel dataset in R but there is one column that its name changed a little bit, just as shown below:

[image]

The original name of the first column is "Id" but it seems to change a little bit. And I make sure I didn't change anything in my original dataset. Just imported it in R and opened, it looks like this. What happened? Thanks many in advance!

Comment: You can use `check.names = FALSE` while reading the dataset.  There could be some special characters as column names that got converted witih the default `check.names = TRUE`

Comment: OK. So what does the check.names = TRUE mean?

Comment: I meant `read.csv("yourfile.csv", check.names = FALSE)`. while TRUE, it triggers the. `make.names` and `make.unique` function which does the checking of column names and change it if it finds anything suspicious or not conforming to the standard format

Comment: Thank you so much! Got that!

Comment: It looks like your file has a UTF byte order marker (BOM) that causes the funny name. Use the suggested fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624796/read-a-utf-8-text-file-with-bom

Answer (score 2):

While reading the dataset use the `check.names = FALSE` in `read.csv/read.table` to prevent the checks of column names

```
dat <- read.csv("file.csv", check.names = FALSE)
```

`check.names = TRUE` (default option) triggers `make.names` and `make.unique` that changes the column names if it doesn't conform to standard format, i.e. it would append `X` at the beginning if the column names start with numbers...

---

If we check the source code of `read.table`

```
 ...

 if (check.names) 
        col.names <- make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE)

 ...
```

and `make.names` calls `make.unique`

```
make.names
function (names, unique = FALSE, allow_ = TRUE) 
{
    names <- as.character(names)
    names2 <- .Internal(make.names(names, allow_))
    if (unique) {
        o <- order(names != names2)
        names2[o] <- make.unique(names2[o])
    }
    names2
}
```

Comment: But my original column name is "Id", I think it's normal, there is no any reason triggering the make.names or something like that.

Comment: @Chris Can you read with `check.names = FALSE` and get the `dput(colnames(yourdata))` I think the character is a special character or may be there is a space before it

Comment: OK. Actually it's a question from my friend and I'm just curious. I will tell him and check if it works!